# How to get quality of jpeg 100? Camera2API

Tags: java, android, image, camera, android-camera

i spend a lot of time with question how to set jpeg quality if you use `Camera2API`, and finally find such solution

I achieved increasing the JPEG quality by adding it as a key to the CaptureRequest.Builder

The JPEG quality is set in the captureStillPicture() method in the Camer2BasicFragment like so:

```
// This is the CaptureRequest.Builder that we use to take a picture.
    final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
    captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

    //Set the JPEG quality here like so
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_QUALITY, (byte)100);
```

Thanks to @BlinkingCahill

but issue is that case if i set quality `100` evetually in saved image i get `96`...

**Maybe someone know how i can get `100`? Or it depends of device or smth else?**

Comment: Can you increase the image quality. I am using Android 6.0 in Galaxy S7 but the quality is still low

Comment: @user3051460 how do you check quality?

Comment: I just open the image and see it by visualization. When I check the size, it has about 755KB/image

Comment: It looks good now.  I changed two line as follows `mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_QUALITY, (byte)100);`

Comment: @user3051460 so now, is it ok?

Comment: Yes, it is fine now with value setting is 100